# Amazon Appstore new update issue

Tags: android, app-store, amazon-appstore

I am trying to update my app in amazon Appstore but getting following error.

**The binary file cannot be uploaded because the package name is already in use. Please change the package name and then upload again**

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, did you try changing the package name to something else?

Comment: I think you better send the issue to support guys at Amazon, than posting it here, cause as it appears, your credentials for uploading the updated version is not the same as the ones, when you uploaded the first version

Comment: to update the app you need to go to the same app detail page and on top there is a button `Add upcoming version` use it to update the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this issue to Amazon support team and my issue got solved in 24hrs time.